# Deploy an Angular App with Node Js and MySql for db?

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment

I want to create a project for my portfolio but i don't know how to deploy an app with those..
Can someone explain me how to do this ?

I didn't try anything but i searched for severals hours and nothing seems interesting..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.